# Move from TFS 2008 to TFS 2010

Tags: tfs, tfsintegrationplatform

We have succesfully built our TFS 2010 infrastructure and the first VM using Visual Studio 2010. Now I have a very simple question. How I can move a solution from our existing TFS 2008 to the new one 2010?
Is there any tool included in TFS?

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, I would recommend that you backup your TFS databases from the original TFS 2008 Data Tier server:

> BACKUP DATABASE TfsActivityLogging
>   TO disk = 'C:\TFS 2008 Upgrade.bak'
>   WITH INIT
>   BACKUP DATABASE TfsBuild
>   TO disk = 'C:\TFS 2008 Upgrade.bak'
>   BACKUP DATABASE TfsIntegration
>   TO disk = 'C:\TFS 2008 Upgrade.bak'
>   BACKUP DATABASE TfsVersionControl
>   TO disk = 'C:\TFS 2008 Upgrade.bak'
>   BACKUP DATABASE TfsWorkItemTracking
>   TO disk = 'C:\TFS 2008 Upgrade.bak'
>   BACKUP DATABASE TfsWorkItemTrackingAttachments
>   TO disk = 'C:\TFS 2008 Upgrade.bak'

Then move the backup file to the new server, and restore them:

> RESTORE DATABASE TfsActivityLogging
>   FROM Disk = 'C:\TFS 2008 Upgrade.bak'
>   WITH RECOVERY,
>   REPLACE,
>   FILE = 1,
>   MOVE 'TfsActivityLogging' to '< DataFileLocation>\TfsActivityLogging.mdf',
>   MOVE 'TfsActivityLogging_log' to '< LogFileLocation>\TfsActivityLogging_log.ldf'
>   RESTORE DATABASE TfsBuild
>   FROM Disk = 'C:\TFS 2008 Upgrade.bak'
>   WITH RECOVERY,
>   REPLACE,
>   FILE = 2,
>   MOVE 'TfsBuild' to '< DataFileLocation>\TfsBuild.mdf',
>   MOVE 'TfsBuild_log' to '< LogFileLocation>\TfsBuild_log.ldf'
>   RESTORE DATABASE TfsIntegration
>   FROM Disk = 'C:\TFS 2008 Upgrade.bak'
>   WITH RECOVERY,
>   REPLACE,
>   FILE = 3,
>   MOVE 'TfsIntegration' to '< DataFileLocation>\TfsIntegration.mdf',
>   MOVE 'TfsIntegration_log' to '< LogFileLocation>\TfsIntegration_log.ldf'
>   RESTORE DATABASE TfsVersionControl
>   FROM Disk = 'C:\TFS 2008 Upgrade.bak'
>   WITH RECOVERY,
>   REPLACE,
>   FILE = 4,
>   MOVE 'TfsVersionControl' to '< DataFileLocation>\Tfs_< TeamProjectCollectionName>.mdf',
>   MOVE 'TfsVersionControl_log' to '< LogFileLocation>\Tfs_< TeamProjectCollectionName>_log.ldf'
>   RESTORE DATABASE TfsWorkItemTracking
>   FROM Disk = 'C:\TFS 2008 Upgrade.bak'
>   WITH RECOVERY,
>   REPLACE,
>   FILE = 5,
>   MOVE 'TfsWorkItemTracking' to '< DataFileLocation>\TfsWorkItemTracking.mdf',
>   MOVE 'TfsWorkItemTracking_log' to '< LogFileLocation>\TfsWorkItemTracking_log.ldf'
>   RESTORE DATABASE TfsWorkItemTrackingAttachments
>   FROM Disk = 'C:\TFS 2008 Upgrade.bak'
>   WITH RECOVERY,
>   REPLACE,
>   FILE = 6,
>   MOVE 'TfsWorkItemTrackingAttachments' to '< DataFileLocation>\TfsWorkItemTrackingAttachments.mdf',
>   MOVE 'TfsWorkItemTrackingAttachments_log' to '< LogFileLocation>\TfsWorkItemTrackingAttachments_log.ldf'

Then, on the new server, run the import command:

> "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 2010\Tools\tfsconfig.exe" import /sqlinstance:server078.live01.lan.local /collectionName:< TeamProjectCollectionName> /confirmed

You should be then ready to go. :)

Comment: I need to move 1 team project at the time, as after we move it we will need additional stuff. With your solution I am just moving the entire TFS 2008 under the new collection in 2010. Is there a less invasive solution? TFS 2008 is our production for now

Comment: Less invasive, no. You have to move everything at once. This does not however mean that you cannot move one Team Project at a time:

When a Team Project is to be migrated, repeat the above process citing a different destination Team Project Collection name, and once imported, through the Administration Console, delete each Team Project that you are not upgrading at that time. If you do this however:

1) You cannot branch from one Team Project Collection into another.
2) Permissions become far more difficult to manage.
3) You need a different build server for each Team Project Collection.

Comment: I would REALLY recommend that you get a repeatable upgrade process in place, and switch from 2008 to 2010 over night.

Answer (score 3):

The Microsoft Rangers produced the following Resources on this some time ago on this:

> [TFS Integration Platform](http://tfsintegration.codeplex.com/)

This includes some tools to assist different migration strategies, along with white papers discussing them, and some nice posters to help guide your thinking.

---

**Edit to add:**

I've also just written a series of blog posts detailing my experiences attempting to do just this:

> [Killing Off TFS 2005 - Part 1](http://www.doodle.co.uk/Blogs.aspx/2011/04/05/Killing-off-TFS-2005-Part-1)

But as a heads up, unless you've got a fairly simple Team Project, you're in for a world of pain - to be fair the documentation that comes with it does warn you of this.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to move one project at a time you can use [Antony Gibb's procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3045349/move-from-tfs-2008-to-tfs-2010/3045537#3045537) and then delete the projects in TFS 2010 that you didn't want to yet move.   Then on the TFS 2008 server delete the project that you did want to have moved.  Example:

You have projects A, B and C on TFS 2008 and you want to move only project A.

1. Perform the above procedure
2. Delete projects B and C from the TFS 2010 after importing
3. Delete project A from the TFS2008 instance.

Comment: What exactly is "above" in this answer? Antony's answer? Because currently your answer is directly below the question, at least on my screen :)

Comment: Yes, Bryan is referring to Antony's answer.

Comment: If you follow Bryan's suggestion, then each import you perform would need to be a seperate Team Project Collection, and is not recommended

Answer (score 0):

Also consider that you may have some things from the old system you don't want to carry over but perhaps do want to be able to look at for posterity. After doing the TFS Integration tool you can then upgrade your old 2008 tfs instance to 2010 (which will have the effect of upgrading your old team collection to the 2010 version and then you could add it as another collection (read only) to your new 2010 instance. Then you have all your history and projects but they don't interfere in your new pristine installation.